# Android Native API (getWidth etc) for determining attributes of images return wrong value

Tags: java, android

In Android while trying to get/set the attributes of an Image I am getting Image attributes as zero which I guess is not a correct value. Please help me on this. here's the excerpt of the code:

**CODE**

```
public class CumulativeGoalProgress extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cumulative_goals);
    showCumulativeGoalProgress();
    }


private void showCumulativeGoalProgress(){

ImageView wellnessBarIndicator =     (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_welness_bar_indicator);

Log.e("Ravi", "progBarImage getBaseline = " + progBarImage.getBaseline());
Log.e("Ravi", "progBarImage getHeight = " + progBarImage.getHeight());
Log.e("Ravi", "progBarImage getMeasuredHeight = " + progBarImage.getMeasuredHeight());
Log.e("Ravi", "progBarImage getMeasuredWidth = " + progBarImage.getMeasuredWidth());
Log.e("Ravi", "progBarImage getWidth = " + progBarImage.getWidth());
Log.e("Ravi", "progBarImage getBottom = " + progBarImage.getBottom());
Log.e("Ravi", "progBarImage getLeft = " + progBarImage.getLeft());
Log.e("Ravi", "progBarImage getNextFocusLeftId = " + progBarImage.getNextFocusLeftId());
Log.e("Ravi", "progBarImage getPaddingLeft = " + progBarImage.getPaddingLeft());
Log.e("Ravi", "progBarImage getPaddingTop = " + progBarImage.getPaddingTop());
}
}
```

**The ImageView as defined in the XML**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_welness_bar_indicator"
    android:layout_marginTop="119px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/vis_wellness_bar_indicator"
    />
```

**vis_wellness_bar_indicator** is the source Image file in PNG format.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that during the `onCreate` phase the view isn't yet constructed, so the image hasn't been loaded into the ImageView yet. Call the same code later, for example on the `OnDraw` or on `OnSizeChanged` method.